# How can i change the default setting of font size in my inbox to read better

Tags: windows-10

I have surface pro 4 and using win 10, when I access to my emails   They are too small to read

Comment: Typically, your email software will have a setting, so you need to edit your question to add what software you're using in order for people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Outlook:

1. On the File tab, choose Options > Mail.
2. The Outlook File tab
3. Under Compose messages, choose Stationery and Fonts.
4. On the Personal Stationery tab, under New mail messages or Replying
   or forwarding messages, choose Font.
5. In the Font box, choose the font, style, size, and color that you
   want to use. You can see a preview of your changes as you make them.
6. Choose OK three times to return to Outlook.

But you can find other Tutorials on Google, DuckDuckGo or on the official homepages :)